# How to delete record more than 48 hours

Tags: mysql

I have a field name date_start using the datetime data type. My question is on how to delete record based on this field that is more than 48 hours.

BTW, just give me the sql statement.

Thank you

Comment: -1 This is not the kind of question you are allowed to ask on StackOverflow. We are not here to spoonfeed you or to do your work for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from your_table
where date_start < ADDTIME(now(), '-48:00:00');
```

Comment: @jaypabs : Then accept answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE date_start < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -48 HOUR)
```

Comment: sorry but this code will also delete the record w/ current date.